# Sort array on timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, timestamp

I have an array of the following format:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      1335541286 => 
        array
          'event' => string 'track' (length=5)
          'title' => string 'Plastic Humans' (length=14)
          'album' => string 'Cities of hunger' (length=16)
          'artist' => string 'The Maple Room' (length=14)
  1 => 
    array
      1335540999 => 
        array
          'event' => string 'track' (length=5)
          'title' => string 'Atlantis' (length=8)
          'album' => string 'Cities of hunger' (length=16)
          'artist' => string 'The Maple Room' (length=14)
  2 => 
    array
      1335540064 => 
        array
          'event' => string 'track' (length=5)
          'title' => string 'Doradus Stars' (length=13)
          'album' => string 'A Glimpse of the Inside' (length=23)
          'artist' => string 'The Maple Room' (length=14)
  3 => 
    array
      1335539855 => 
        array
          'event' => string 'track' (length=5)
          'title' => string 'In Twenty Five' (length=14)
          'album' => string 'A Glimpse of the Inside' (length=23)
          'artist' => string 'The Maple Room' (length=14)
  4 => 
    array
      1334016000 => 
        array
          'event' => string 'purchase' (length=8)
          'title' => string 'Donald Trump - Single' (length=21)
          'artist' => string 'Mac Miller' (length=10)
          'format' => string '10"' (length=3)
```

I would love to sort the array based on the key, which is the timestamp. I've read a lot about PHP sorting methods but i can't figure out what the best solution would be.

Any help is appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using minified data:

```
$data = array(
  array('1335541286' => array('1')),
  array('1335540999' => array('1')),
  array('1335540064' => array('1')),
);

usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
  return key($a) - key($b);
});

print_r($data);
```

Also the structure of your input data seems a bit strange. The extra level is not really needed and complicates stuff unnecessarily.

Comment: I need it so I can use the same timestamp for multiple items

Comment: @turncoat Then I would use the timestamp as the key with an array of items as value. Removing the first tier in the array, and enabling `ksort` directly.

Comment: I thought you cannot use the same key in an array

Comment: @turncoat, you'd have `array(timestamp => array(array(value1), array(value2), ..., array(valueN)), nextTimestamp => ...)`.

Comment: Radu solution works for me. I'll prefer that so I don't need to rework my array structure.

Comment: @turncoat, you really should consider doing this. In the long run, it will be hugely easier to maintain and extend. Besides, Yoshi's solution is almost identical to mine, but more compact and likely slightly faster...

Comment: @turncoat This version also works without reworking the array. My comment was just an additional suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
uasort($array, 'cmp');

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (key($a) == key($b)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (key($a) < key($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}
```